# Unhandled exception

Tags: wpf, exception, unhandled-exception

What is the best way to handle an unhandled exception in a WPF application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `DispatcherUnhandledException`:

XAML (App.xaml):

```
<Application x:Class="App.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="wndMain.xaml" DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
```

Code Behind (App.xaml.cs/vb:

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle error here

    ...

    // Prevent default unhandled exception processing by WPF
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Read up [more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx). Always do the correct amount of error handling in the first place though. Don't just let errors slip into this method.