# Terminate application after unhandled exception

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have a problem in a WPF application. I wrote this code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
            UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
    }

    void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "ERROR",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    ...
}
```

but when a unhandled exception happens, a lot of MessageBox appear to the screen (the exception happens in a timed routine) and after closing one of them, Windows signals that there is an unhandled exception.
How can I avoid multiple MessageBoxes?
How can I avoid the message of an unhandled exception?
How can I terminate the application after the exception?
As you can easily suppose, I would like to show a message (but only one) with my MessageBox and then terminate the application without any other message.
In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251868/unhandled-exception) related to this argument, [Kyle Rozendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103385/kyle-rozendo) told me to use DispatcherUnhandledException. Is it necessary or the code I written is sufficient?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid multiple messageboxes by initializing a static boolean `firstTime` to `true` and use the code within the Exception handler:

```
void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (firstTime){
        Exception exception = e.ExceptionObject as Exception; 
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "ERROR", 
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error); 
        firstTime = false;
   }else{
        // Now kill the process....
   }
}
```

To terminate the process do this, within the `MyHandler`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
proc.Kill();
```

Comment: What about DispatcherUnhandledException? Is it necessary too?

Comment: DispatcherUnhandledException is not necessary. Have you tried the code to see if that worked..because the code will shutdown the application...

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `Application.Exit()` or `System.Environment.Exit(exitCode)` to immediately shut down your application after you have shown your error dialog box.

Comment: Minor note.. Application.Exit() will not work if the exception happens before Application.Run