# Where should AppDomain.UnhandledException be subscribed to?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

**The suggested duplicate** is about `DispatcherUnhandledException`, not `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

**Original**:

Where should `AppDomain.UnhandledException` be subscribed to? The example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)  just shows it in `Main`, which is what I do in Winforms: I subscribe to it in **Program.Main** :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

But I can't find a suitable place for it in WPF where `Main` is hidden. I've searched, but mainly found discussions of *whether* to subscribe to it, assuming the reader would now where.

Comment: You can do this in *app.xaml.cs*. See: [unhandled exception][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251868/unhandled-exception

Comment: @musium That's only for `DispatcherUnhandledException`. At least intellisense doesn't show the same for `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.

Comment: This is the nearest thing to UnhandledException (Winforms) in WPF.
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @musium No. It's not. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1472562/939213 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Main() entrypoint in a WPF is auto-generated from the App.xaml source file.  Earliest opportunity you have to subscribe the event is in the constructor for the App class in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application {
    public App() {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

This is however not "perfect", you cannot detect any failure in field initializers of your Application class.  As well as any JIT compilation failures of types you use in your Application class, missing assemblies or versioning problems being the usual troublemakers.

To avoid missing those, you need to give up on the auto-generated code and write your own Main() method.  With the assumption that you did not heavily modify the app.xaml file.  Delete that file from the project and add a new class, I'd suggest Program.cs :)  And make it look similar to this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    class Program {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
            Start();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static void Start() {
            var app = new App();
            app.Run(new MainWindow());
        }

        private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
            // etc..
        }
    }

    public class App : Application {
        // etc..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you created the project with the default template in Visual Studio, you should have a file named `app.xaml` and under it another file named `app.xaml.cs`.

Inside the `App` class you can add it at the beginning of `OnStartup` (along with the `Dispatcher.UnhandledException`):

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // don't forget to call base implementation
    base.OnStartup(e);

    Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
}
```

Actually, `Dispatcher.UnhandledException` should be sufficient in most cases. Meaning you can skip using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` altogether. The only reason to also register to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` would be to get exceptions raised in threads other than the main UI thread. But I think that it is better practice to actually catch those exceptions in their respective thread.

Comment: Thank you but I was also editing it. And I would do it differently.

Comment: No problem. Go ahead :)

Comment: I prefer to set the callbacks before calling the base implementation. Is this a good practice?

Comment: I would say calling the WPF base code is more important than your own calls. In this case I wouldn't do that, or use a `try... catch` to make sure it gets called.

Comment: Fair enough. Also in that particular case I don't think it matters: I don't see what could possibly go wrong with registering the two delegates.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `OnStartup` method in your `App.xaml.cs`, which is the closest you get to the `Main` method (or use the `App` constructor` if you will)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // register the event handler here
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }
}
```

Note that this requires you to omit the `StartupUri` and open a `Window` yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a `base` OnStartup I'll have to call after that or is it usually empty?

Comment: Yes, you should call it: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,f2c567e5642bd030

Comment: @xanatos: Indeed. Removed it by accident from the sample code I copied. Even if it does nothing now I usually include it.